# Serialization/Deserialization strategy for byte stream of C structs in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers, marshalling

I'm working on a Client app, written in C#, which should communicate with a legacy app (let's call it a server). The problem is that the server's API is represented as a bunch of plain old C structs. Every struct has a 4-byte header and the data that follows it. It's just a byte stream.

I understand that this particular binary format is unique (given by the legacy server app). Because of that, it's not possible to use any SerDes libraries like Protocol Buffers, which uses its way of encoding binary data.

- Is there any project/library for binary serialization that allows me to specify the type of message (like protobuff does) and its binary format? Every library I've seen was based either on JSON, XML, or proprietary binary format.
- Suppose I would decide to write my own SerDes library (in C#). What would be the best/recommended strategy for doing this? I want to do it the professional way, at least once in my life. Thanks!

PS: *We're talking about little-endian only.*

This is how the server defines a message:

```
struct Message1
{
    byte    Size;       // Header 1st byte
    byte    Type;       
    byte    ReqI;       
    byte    Zero;       //Header 4th byte.

    word    UDPPort;    // Actual data starts here.
    word    Flags;      

    byte    Sp0;        
    byte    Prefix;     
    word    Interval;   

    char    Admin[16];  
    char    IName[16];  
};
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how the C# app will communicate with the legacy app. If the legacy app is unmanaged code, you should review about  marshaling, interop and platform invoke. If the legacy app is managed code, it should be far more easy to communicate.

Comment: The legacy app is an unmanaged code (it's written in pure C). Communication between client and server is done using a standard socket connection.

Comment: Well, there is no room for serialization in that way. You have to read bytes from the network stream and parse according documentation. Serialization, as I understood, is a two stage process. Data is serialized in one end, transmited by some medium and deserialized in the other end to recreate original status.

Comment: Tip: you can creat structs in C# with explicit layout that exactly mimic the C code (see "fixed buffers" for the last few fields); then you can use spans and MemoeyMarshal.Cast, and boom: byte[] in, typed data out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have fixed sized c structs being sent via a socket connection and you need to interpret those into handy C# classes.

The easiest way may be to do all the message handling in code written in managed C++. In that you’d have a structure that, possibly with a bunch of pragmas, I’m sure could be made to have the same memory layout as the structure being sent through the socket. You would then also define a similar managed c++ class (eg containing managed strings instead of char arrays). You would also write code that converts the struct field by field into one of these managed classes. Wrap the whole thing up in a DLL, and include it in your C# project as a dependency.

The reason for this is because managed C++, weird though it is as a language, is a far easier bridge between unmanaged and managed code and data structures. There’s no need to marshall anything, this is done for you. I’ve used his route to create libraries that make calls into Windows’ hardware discovery facilities, for which there isn’t (or wasn’t) any pre-existing C# library. Using managed C++ code to call the necessary win32 functions was far easier than doing the same thing from C#.

Good luck!